# Oracle 10g express and 11g express DB homepage is not showing up

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I just installed Oracle for the first time. To test the installation, I tried to check the home page. The browser opened a local website, but the website doesn't exist.

I tried 10g first, then uninstalled it and tried 11g. I always get a non-running webpage. I tried it because I saw in some answers that 10g was not supported by Windows 7 32 bits and that 11g was.

Each time, I checked if all the Oracle services were up and they are. I also checked if the port 8080 was used and it is not. Also, disabling the Windows firewall gives nothing.

What is wrong, and how do I fix it? What service is supposed to start the website, and where is its log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my teammate found the answer. The problem was in the installation and here is what worked:

> **Warning for Windows7 only**:
>   Oracle 10g installation on windows 7
>   32-bit completes without error but it is incomplete. In order to fix
>   the problem, before installing Oracle, shut down your PC, unplug your
>   network cable, boot your PC and install Oracle (not a joke), and
>   reconnect only after the installation of Oracle 10g.

That is weird, but it worked

NOTE----This  method doesn't worked with 11g  express R2 .  (ofcourse i am talking of windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) First, make sure it's running. It sounds like it is from the error message you got in step 2, but double check that the Services (OracleServiceXE and OracleXETNSListener) are both started. Those are the only two services you need, and it does sound like the OracleServiceXE may not be running.

2) Make sure it's not running on a non-8080 port. From a command prompt, run netstat -an and see if anything is listening on port 8080. I've seen it get installed on alternate ports (including 9080) in the past.

3) If there's something listening on port 8080, try http://localhost:8080/ in your browser. If there's something on 9080, try that.

Comment: Service process ORACLE.EXE for OracleServiceXE is running on port no. 50944 after i manually started it from services.msc. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue and fixed by following the below steps.

go to your Oracle XE 10g console using sqlplus. Replace mypassword with that your SYS user password (as specified during the installation process). Note that the number 2, 3, 4 at the left side is generated by the sqlplus tools prompt (you don't need to type them in).

```
[sourcecode lang="sql"]
C:\> sqlplus sys/mypassword@xe as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Jun 18 17:53:47 2009
Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle. All rights reserved.
```

Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

```
SQL> begin
2 dbms_xdb.sethttpport('8484');
3 end;
4 /
[/sourcecode]
```

Oracle XE should reply:

```
[sourcecode lang="sql"]
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
[/sourcecode]
```

After that check to ensure that the configuration has been changed properly:

```
[sourcecode lang="sql"]
SQL> select dbms_xdb.gethttpport as "HTTP-Port is " from dual;
[/sourcecode]
```

You should get a message like this:

```
[sourcecode lang="sql"]
HTTP-Port is
------------
8484
[/sourcecode]
```

Exit from sqlplus by typing "exit" at the prompt.
Now restart the PC and check.e same issue.